# Convert hashed password to string werkuzeug python

Tags: python, security, hash, werkzeug

I am using Werkzeug for password hashing so that the passwords entered by users will be safe(atleast).

Lets say my application is as follows:

When a user gets logged in I will use check_password_hash and then login the user inside.

After the user is logged in, I want to show them their password.

The problem I am encountering:

How do I convert the hashed password back to string to show the user their password?

My code is as follows:

```
>>> import werkzeug.security as ws
>>> ws.generate_password_hash('abcdefg')
'pbkdf2:sha1:1000$fYAXLNA6$637528ae2fa195304c328d585e805b164f1c718f'
>>> ws._hash_internal('pbkdf2:sha1:1000', 'fYAXLNA6', 'abcdefg')
('637528ae2fa195304c328d585e805b164f1c718f', 'pbkdf2:sha1:1000')
```

Now how do I convert this '6375.....'  back to 'abcdefg'?

I have access to database and the all the other stuff required. Basically I am the admin!

Note: I cannot use the password which user entered while logging in. I can only use the password from database.

Comment: Why do you want to show the password to the user?

Comment: Actually the password is not shown to the user, this password will be used to scrape another website(https://vtop.vit.ac.in/parent/parent_login.asp) and get the attendance of the user automatically without the need to enter all the DOB, Mobile number stuff, I will store a session and whenever user logs in then they can check their attendance.

Comment: I see, that's a different problem. You should have made it clear in your question, otherwise my answer is the usual answer. You need to write your own password manager. What they usually do is encrypt the data with a master password, but the question is what master password to use.

Answer (score 2):

> After the user is logged in, I want to show them their password.

The whole purpose and reason of hashing a password is that you can never do this. Not you, not anyone else.

If someone has access or steals the database with the list of passwords, converting the hash back to the original password is really, really expensive. You will need a million years to break and reverse one single password.

Comment: So is there any solution instead of using password hashing, with which I can implement this without compromising on the safety?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot get the original text back while using hashing. Generally all the passwords are stored as hash value, in order to make the passwords private (known only to the user). All the servers implement this. If you want to get the password back then you should use symmetric key cryptography. Where a secret key will be shared between the clients and the server **(But it is a very bad practice)** It better that you go with hashing.